# FLUTTER/DART - TEXT not displaying to home.dart file within a FloatingActionButton

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Having a problem with getting text to display in my home.dart file when it's entered in the FloatingActionButton.

Below is the code sample. Any suggestions where I am getting it wrong. I believe that the 'String value;' line must be within the same MaterialButton function, though not sure how to do it without ruining it further.

}[image: Here is the code within IDE]`

Comment: It's better to include the code instead of screenshot of the code, so people can support you quicker ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a simple app here to demonstrade the behavior. You can test by copy and running this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  String value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _createDialog(context);
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _createDialog(context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('title'),
          content: TextField(
            onChanged: (text) {
              value = text;
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('buttonText'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bach. Do you recommend I put in separate Classes and StatelessWidgets for each? Also, can you recommend how I can get the 'Add' button on the Home Class?

Comment: @Spixol Yes it would be easier to manage the State. About the Add button, you means placing it within the Home class?

Comment: Hey mate, I did as you said and it is almost identical like to your code above, though the text input is still showing on a different screen. I want it to go as listview on the landing page, where the FloatingActionButton is. Do you have any idea how I can get this achieved?

Comment: @Spixol If understand correctly, you want to display the output without navigation right? Just updated my answer for it

Comment: perfect bro. Get yourself a beer!

Comment: @Spixol Thanks mate, would appreciate if got chosen as accepted answer ^^